# why corona's in app purchase shows this error message on my phone?

Tags: android, coronasdk

I just run the sample project of Corona SDK that has in app purchases

when I run the APK on my phone (Nexus 5) with (Android M), it shows this error message when I tap on the provided buttons.

As far as I know, IAP don't require an extra license now, Correct?

and IAP is allowed on my phone, I tried to buy something from another app, and it showed up the buying screen.

I wish someone can help, Thanks

[image]
[image]
**This also happened in an android 4 powered samsung device.